# product of bessel function integral

Tags: integration

[image]

Is this formula is true for s=-1

Comment: Why would it be invalid for $s=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

You can check by noting that this integral evaluates to $0$ for $s=-1$ when $0<b<a$...